# Are en-dash, em-dash, hyphen, minus sign, and quotation dash superfluous?

Tags: punctuation

I believe one major reason that proper usage of en-dash, em-dash, hyphen, minus sign, and quotation dash can be so frustrating is because they convey information already given by the context of the mark.

Are there instances where the use of one of the strikingly similar punctuation marks listed would resolve an ambiguity? I am struggling to imagine a phrase which could be interpreted differently depending on which punctuation was used, and I am confident I have never closely inspected the length of one of these marks in order to better understand a statement.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that there really are only two different symbols, in practice.  The hyphen is used for hyphenated words (and minus sign and a few other non-linguistic purposes).  The dash (usually typed as a double hyphen) is used to represent a separation or pause in speech or thought.  Unless you're a typesetter or have OCD the other terms are superfluous.

Comment: This is not a question about English for which there can be an answer, it is one of  the “…types of questions should I avoid asking?” in the Help Centre in the category:  ‘there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.’”. (Or perhaps “a rant in disguise: ‘______ sucks, am I right?’”).

Comment: One typeface's n-dash is another typeface's ...

Comment: @HotLicks : I was only made aware of these because a publication of mine came back with a grumpy rant about my misuse of them a few years back.

Comment: @David : although I admit that I view these marks as an over-complication, I did my best to make the question answerable and not a rant. I am genuinely trying to determine if I should make an effort alter my everyday usage or else stand confidently defiant in my complete disregard for these different punctuation marks.

Comment: The minus sign seems a little out of place in this list, as its "proper" use is a matter of mathematical typography (in which it is preferred to have a symbol with the same width as the plus sign) rather than English language & usage.

Comment: @HotLicks Good thing I’m a typesetter, then, ’cause I definitely use both hypens, en dashes, and em dashes in regular writing (e.g. “A one-way ticket London–Paris—quite a short distance—is ridiculously expensive”), and I’m quite sure I don’t have OCD. ;-)

Comment: But hey, doesn't it look somewhat more aesthetic with proper use of those?

Comment: @David how is "Are there instances where the use of one of the strikingly similar punctuation marks listed in the tile would resolve an ambiguity?" opinion based? That is absolutely answerable.

Comment: In "everyday" usage you only need the hyphen and the dash.  Most word processors will convert a double hyphen to a dash automatically, so you never need to resort to "special characters", even on works of "literature".  And it is perfectly acceptable to use a double hyphen ( `--`) as a dash without special treatment in ordinary use for, eg, Stack Exchange questions.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I find that using the dash without surrounding spaces is confusing and ugly.

Comment: @HotLicks Which one? Em dashes used for parentheticals are generally not set off by spaces (sometimes hair spaces or thin spaces are used, but not full spaces), and en dashes used for ranges should _never_ be set off by any kind of space. En dashes used for parentheticals are normally set off by full spaces (often non-breaking ones on the ‘inside’). I find that setting off em dashes with full spaces is ugly, but like your statement, that is mere opinion.

Comment: @terdon - One important point is that, given differences in media, type faces, and composition, it is difficult to impossible to tell the difference between, say, an en-dash and an em-dash.  The purpose of such punctuation should be to ADD clarity, and when one has to stop and examine a character and make a judgment call as to whether it's an en-dash or an em-dash, that is it not helping clarity.  JBJ's example of "A one-way ticket London–Paris—quite..." is confusing -- it would be far clearer to simply replace the en-dash with "to".

Comment: @HotLicks OK, but that doesn't make the question which is asking whether there is ever a difference between four punctuation marks. Or did you mean to reply to Janus?

Comment: @terdon — …as the schoolchild protested to the teacher. You can't be serious — the question starts "I believe…".The situation is explained quite clearly in https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. And, believe it or not, I was doing my civic duty by reviewing first posts and making appropriate comments.

Comment: @David I never said you weren't! I just dont' agree that this is opinion based so did *my* civic duty and made my disagreement public. Anyway, the post may start with *I believe* but the question doesn't. The question is simply asking whether there are any cases where choosing one of the mentioned punctuation marks over the other might resolve an ambiguity. And as Hellion and others showed below, there certainly are such cases and this isn't a question of opinion.

Comment: @tendon — …and also isn't a question about English. It is one of many questions of the form "I don't see the reason for this rule and want to break it. Will someone on the list say it's ok so i can justify doing so."

Comment: @David : "I don't see the reason for this rule and want to break it. Will someone on the list say it's ok so i can justify doing so." is half correct... My thought was more like "I don't see the reason for this rule and want to understand the rule better."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can easily construct a "garden-path" sentence based on a phrasal verb where the choice of punctuation can clearly show whether you meant it to be a phrasal verb or not:

> She was upset by my carrying-on top of everything else-her credit card.
>   She was upset by my carrying—on top of everything else—her credit card.

In the first sentence, you have to stop and reinterpret "carrying-on" as not being a gerund form of "carry on" but as a simple verb, interrupted by a prepositional clause.  The use of the em-dash is not strictly necessary, but it is clearly an aid to smooth reading.

Comment: This example is all very well but a dash is often set off by spaces (en-dash or hyphen abused as dash, not em-dash) which would give a decent clue as to the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Well done! I did trip on that first one.

Comment: I feel (but can't find examples to support) that this kind of problem would be even worse at the end of lines, where hyphens are used for continuation.

Comment: IDGI, I interpret both of those as entirely identical sentences with identical meaning.

Comment: @DeadMG: A "garden path sentence" is one that you (or at least, some readers) have to re-parse earlier parts of. Some readers will first read this sentence as "She was upset by my carrying-on...", i.e. "I was carrying on [acting in an inappropriate and attention-grabbing way], and that upset her".

Comment: Like DeadMG I interpret those as sentences with identical meaning… so will most readers who haven’t read your style book.

Almost all readers will think you wrong to use any dash without spaces… *carrying-on*, not *carrying - on*

Those assertions remain axiomatic until you produce even a handful of readers who claim to have followed your logic without prior knowledge.

I’m sorry to say this and the suggestion that different dashes impart different meanings is interesting more as a measure of its misplaced obsessive compulsion than anything to do with language, printing or writing.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin but they are sentences with identical meaning.  The issue is only that it takes more effort to arrive at the meaning when the "wrong" dash is used, because that encourages a misinterpretation.

Comment: @Hellion Thanks and that's simply not true.

It wasn't true when you first said it, it wasn't true when DeadMG noticed, it wasn't true when I noticed and it won't be true when your readers notice.

It does not take more effort to arrive at the meaning when the *wrong* dash is used and that does not encourage any kind of misinterpretation.

I’m still sorry and still, nothing you said is remotely true except for people with specific prior knowledge… and if you think specific prior knowledge is the same as comprehension, please explain how…

Answer (score 11):

The purpose of hyphens and dashes and, indeed, virtually all punctuation and other printing conventions is not generally to add meaning but rather to make parsing the existing meaning faster, easier, and/or more pleasant.

So you could write

> I am expecting to fill two interview slots—one from 12:30–1:00 p.m. and another from 2:30–3:00 p.m.—for the secretary-treasurer position.

using all one symbol:

> I am expecting to fill two interview slots-one from 12:30-1:00 p.m. and another from 2:30-3:00 p.m.-for the secretary-treasurer position.

But the former is, to me, at least a little bit easier on the eyes and a little bit easier to comprehend on the first pass.

Note that even conventions like [different cases of letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case), or [spaces between words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(punctuation)), are not an inherent feature of written language (see Wikipedia). Obviously, even the second sentence above is significantly easier to understand than

> IAMEXPECTINGTOFILLTWOINTERVIEWSLOTSONEFROM1230100PMANDANOTHERFROM230300PMFORTHESECRETARYTREASURERPOSITION

but even that can be deciphered based on contextual clues.

Of course, there are a myriad of other printing conventions that professional typesetters use to make reading a more seamless and enjoyable experience, that we don't attempt to duplicate in everyday communications (for example, customized [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning), or adjusting the space between letters, just to name one of the most basic). And it is possible to make substitutions for most dashes and hyphens; this is largely a matter of style and personal preference. For example:

> I am expecting to fill two interview slots (one from twelve-thirty to one in the afternoon, and another from two-thirty to three) for the combined secretary and treasurer position.

However, most of us would like the option to use some aspects of the first example, so hyphens and dashes are probably not going away anytime soon.

Bottom line, if the extra keystrokes required for various dashes is really bothersome to you, you can leave them out; you can either use extra hyphens to approximate them, or substitute other punctuation or extra words to clarify your meaning (or live with the possibility of ambiguity and re-reading on the part of your audience). However, keeping them in your writing toolbox will give you more options for writing sentences clearly and concisely.

Comment: Is the premise "The purpose of [...] virtually all punctuation and other printing conventions is not generally to add meaning but rather to make parsing the existing meaning faster, easier, and/or more pleasant" really true? 

There is a big difference between "Let's eat grandma!" and "Let's eat, grandma!"

Comment: @7yl4r My point isn't that punctuation doesn't help with clarifying potentially ambiguous statements, it's that it *does* help, even though it is theoretically possible to get by without it. If commas didn't exist, the 1st version would usually still *mean* you want Grandma to come eat, it just would be harder to tell when it was really an exhortation to cannibalism. At one time, for example, the sentence [might have been punctuated *Let's eat. Grandma.*](http://www.applet-magic.com/punctuation.htm) That worked, sort of, but that doesn't mean commas are redundant or un-useful.

Comment: +1 for "The purpose of hyphens and dashes and, indeed, virtually all punctuation and other printing conventions is not generally to add meaning but rather to make parsing the existing meaning faster, easier, and/or more pleasant."

Comment: @7yl4r Real life example: Just the other day I watched a literature discussion on TV. One participant ranted several minutes that the German translation of the book "God help this child" used the title "Gott, hilf dem Kind" as if the original had a comma (i.e., "God, help the child").

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Presumably they wanted it to be _Gott helfe dem Kind_?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet without context it's a bit hard to say, but "God help this child" was likely an exclamation meaning something like "this is a very troublesome child (to the extent that I need to appeal to higher powers to deal with it)", whereas the German translation reads as a literal request to God to help the child with something. I'm not convinced removing the comma would be much of an improvement if that's the case, it should probably be something like "Gott hilf mir mit diesem Kind" – slightly different meaning, but gets the same feeling across.

Answer (score 6):

I think this pair works. The first is a plausible sentence (think sailing), and if you wrote the second instead of the first, people would have a very hard time figuring out what you meant.

> I found the wind—up river from the Jones's house.
>   I found the wind-up river from the Jones's house.

But I think the only pair of punctuation marks that might create ambiguity are the hyphen and the dash.

Comment: I don’t see what’s so difficult about the second one. Do you not wind up your rivers where you live? :-þ

Answer (score 5):

The n-dash (–) is used for ranges and the dash (-) for hyphenation. These two cases can yield ambiguity.

For example, "*a-b*" implies a pairing and "*a−b*" implies a range—these are very different.

Comment: If you're talking about some specific discipline, please name it.

Otherwise no; not in general English, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose Margot Beste-Chetwynde (from the novel *Decline and Fall*) collaborates on a mathematical paper with Paul Pennyfeather. Their theorem might well be called the **Pennyfeather–Beste-Chetwynde Theorem**, with an en-dash between the names and a hyphen inside the double-barrelled name.

Comment: I see the ambiguity your use of the en-dash is trying to resolve, and agree that something is needed to resolve it. However, I do not think that is proper usage of the en-dash (is it?), and I do not think it successfully resolves the ambiguity (the hyphen and en-dash look too similar for this usage).

Comment: It seems very clear 7yl4r is vastly more right than wrong.

Why is it not clear that the Pennyfeather–Beste-Chetwynde Theorem needs spaces around the dash between Pennyfeather and Beste… and not between Beste-Chetwynde?

Why is it not clear that two different names working together are not to be treated in anything like the same way as a single double-barrelled name?